# Templates in CP take over 4 minutes to load

Tags: templates, control-panel, memory-limit

When I click on design/template/edit/XXXX/index or view the page is taking over minutes to load. Same issue under ADMIN. All othe sections load super fast.

related question [Fatal: Error Message in EE CP when I want to open a template pr submit changes to a template](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/17515/fatal-error-message-in-ee-cp-when-i-want-to-open-a-template-pr-submit-changes-to)

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 67108864 bytes exhausted (tried to
>   allocate 49 bytes) in
>   /home/content/94/9617594/html/control/codeigniter/system/database/drivers/mysql/mysql_result.php
>   on line 147

Comment: Are you using safe mode ?
some times some functions are closed by your hosting provider

Comment: We need more info that that to help. Please see [How do I ask a good question?](http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). At the very least, we need versions of EE, PHP, details about your hosting provider, screenshots of your browser's network tab, and exact URLs which do and do not run slow. I have no idea what "same issue under ADMIN" means either.

Comment: Do you use "Save Templates as files" option? What hosting do you use?

Comment: No Not in Safe Mode.

Comment: No do not save templates as files. My hosting company is godaddy on a shared server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok. Let summarize:

Hosting: Goddady

EE version: **2.1.3**

Do you use "Save Templates as files" option (*Design > Template Manager > Global Template Preferences*): **Yes**

Why templates is load so slow? You have 24 uniq templates

```
SELECT DISTINCT(template_name) FROM `exp_templates`
```

but **67866** records (49 Mb) in exp_templates table. I can't tell you why this happens (is not good strategy to spend time to debug soo old version. Can be something with file permissions or ee bug), but you [not uniq with this issue and version 2.1.3](http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/188007/#890173)

My recommendation:

1. check if you template folder (*/themes/site_themes*) have a good permissions
2. check if you have the last template version in files
3. backup db
4. cleanup exp_templates table
5. recreate templates
6. **update your EE version**

Comment: Dear Max Thank you very mmuch for your help. I will slowly follow your recommedations and report back