# Fatal Error Message in EE CP when I want to open a template pr submit changes to a template

Tags: templates, control-panel, admin

Sorry very new to EE.
What do I do to sort out the following error

Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 67108864 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 49 bytes) in /home/content/94/9617594/html/control/codeigniter/system/database/drivers/mysql/mysql_result.php on line 147

Thanks

Comment: if site online, send me message to max at eec.ms and I will look

Comment: Yes the site is on-line. The error appears when in control panel when I make a change to a template

Answer (score 1):

the same issue as in [Templates in CP take over 4 minutes to load](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/17514/templates-in-cp-take-over-4-minutes-to-load). Happens because too many template publications in DB (67k templates records in exp_templates table).

Comment: Thanks Max for having a look. So I just need to remove the unused templates in the DB exp_templates table?